SAP PI/PO - SFTP FCC Receiver Channel -> XML to TXT Content Conversion
I have the following payload:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<row>Erro 1</row>
<row>Erro 2</row>
<row>Erro 3</row>
...
</root>

The element row is a string array element.
I'm using and SFTP Adapter with FCC Message Protocol to convert this XML into a .txt file.
Expected result:
Erro 1
Erro 2
Erro 3

I've this configuration in the Content Conversion

According to chatGPT and Copilot this should work, but when I open the output .txt, the file is always empty.
Initially, chatGPT and Copilot suggest that the issue might be with the namespaces, so I created a XLS mapping to remove the namespace references.
I also tried to add the root in Recordset Structure, but still the same issue.
Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?
